# Sonatype Insight - Application Health Check - Is it ok to share application composition details to the remote Sonatype Insight Server

Tags: sonatype

Has anybody used the `Sonatype Insight-Application Health Checker` ? It requires you to scan your application ( `war`, `jar`, `zip` etc ) and then uploads its findings onto the `Sonatype Insight Server`. After this, you get the report via the email which also contains an online link to the interactive report.

The problem that i find with this approach is that my application composition details get uploaded to a remote server ( outside my organizational control ) and then the report gets published at an online link which can be accessed by anyone. I do not want this. Is there a way to generate this report without uploading the details to the 'remote server' ?

But the bigger question is, are application owners and organizations ready to share their application composition details to a server outside their reach while performing IP audits on their applications ?

Please let me know what the general pereception about this is ?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you're only sending meta-data about your open source usage - that's not sensitive information.
If you have privacy issues, you can also check out White Source software that provide similar service on cloud.

Answer (score 1):

lots of people use the system to generate a quick and easy manifest of their application based on open source component use. If you a are concerned about anyone else theoretically knowing what open source components you are using, then you may be interested in our on-premises version of this tool for enterprises.